# graph not working properly in django, getting syntax error

Tags: javascript, django

I am new to Django, I want that user should be able to see the count of total user registered in that month, and will count chnages on every month

view.py

```
   monthly_data = (
        Clinic.objects
        .filter(updated__range=(start_of_month, end_of_month))
        .annotate(month=TruncMonth('updated'))
        .values('month')
        .annotate(count=Count('register_clinic_user_id'))
        .order_by('month')
    )
    labels = [data['month'].strftime('%B %Y') for data in monthly_data]
    data = [{'month': data['month'].strftime('%B %Y'), 'count': data['count']} for data in monthly_data]
    graph_data = json.dumps(data)
    print("------------------------------------", graph_data)
    print("----------------------------------------", labels)
```

js

```
new Chart(ctx2, {
      type: "line",
      
      data: {
        labels: ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
        datasets: 
        [
          {
            label: {% for label in labels %} {{label}}, {%endfor%},
            tension: 0.4,
            borderWidth: 0,
            pointRadius: 0,
            borderColor: "#16b385",
            borderWidth: 3,
            backgroundColor: gradientStroke1,
            fill: true,
            data: {% for graph_datas in graph_data %} {{graph_datas}}, {%endfor%},
            maxBarThickness: 6,
          },
        ],
      },
      options: {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        plugins: {
          legend: {
            display: false,
          }
        },
        interaction: {
          intersect: false,
          mode: 'index',
        },
        scales: {
          y: {
            grid: {
              drawBorder: false,
              display: true,
              drawOnChartArea: true,
              drawTicks: false,
              borderDash: [5, 5]
            },
            ticks: {
              display: true,
              padding: 10,
              color: '#b2b9bf',
              font: {
                size: 11,
                family: "Open Sans",
                style: 'normal',
                lineHeight: 2
              },
            }
          },
          x: {
            grid: {
              drawBorder: false,
              display: false,
              drawOnChartArea: false,
              drawTicks: false,
              borderDash: [5, 5]
            },
            ticks: {
              display: true,
              color: '#b2b9bf',
              padding: 20,
              font: {
                size: 11,
                family: "Open Sans",
                style: 'normal',
                lineHeight: 2
              },
            }
          },
        },
      },
    });
```

**error**

syntax error - {% for graph_datas in graph_data %} {{graph_datas}}, {%endfor%} not accepting this syntax,
if i am trying to put this in '{% for graph_datas in graph_data %} {{graph_datas}}, {%endfor%}' it don't show any thing on the graph

Please help
Thanks for your help in advance